# Configuring IIS Web Application with Apache Load Balancer

Tags: apache, iis, load-balancing

i have a website in IIS path and  i have converted it to web application url https://10.0.0.5:9090/test/home.html and i want to use Apache Load balancer along with IIS which serves my website on the same server. My website is built on asp.net. On my server i have installed IIS and an Apache2.4 Load balancer. I want to use the apache2.4 to send the traffic to IIS by request. Before i could do that by adding each IIS page one by one in httpd-ahssl. In order to avoid that i created a directory in IIS to redirect every request containing test directory in the url instead of adding each and every page in httpd-ahssl. I have added the cluster in httpd file and also in httpd-ahssl the proxy for path /test/ but i couldnt make it to work. I made a research but i couldnt find articles with directions of using IIS web applications with Apache2.4. 
The configuration i have tried without success is :

Httpd:
Proxy "balancer://mycluster"
    BalancerMember "https://10.0.0.5:9090"
/Proxy

Httpd-ahssl:
ProxyPass "/test" "balancer://mycluster/test"
ProxyPassReverse "/test" "balancer://mycluster/test"

Do i need to change a setting in IIS?
Can anyone that used similar configuration to share the correct configuration that i have to use?

Comment: your question is not clear ,Could you please elaborate the question ? are you using httpd in front of IIS ? it's not clear whther you have two servers (both iis and httpd) or just want to use httpd instead of IIS. IIS webapplications are nothing special where it just creates it's own worker process to run the website when it comes to static pages.If you have IIS specific technologies running(asp.net,asp etc),then you cannot run those on httpd or any other servers.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope is more clear now. Let me know